# How to test a private Google sheets add on

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working on a Google Sheets add on. I have implemented some basic logic in https://script.google.com/ with Code.gs, index.html, appsscript.json. I deployed the project by clicking Deploy -> New Deployment. I have the deployment id. Then I open a SpreadSheet and click on Add-ons -> Get Add-ons. Basically, I don't see a way to test my private add-on by the deployment id. Are there any docs I'm missing?

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With the new editor, you can install an un-published add-on following these steps:

- Open the script project in the Apps Script editor.
- Click Deploy > Test deployments.
- Click Install.
- At the bottom, click Done.

Once installed, the add-on is immediately available in host applications it extends. You may need to refresh the host application tab before the add-on appears. You must also authorize the add-on before using it.

Documentation for new editor: https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/testing-gsuite-addons#new-editor

Documentation for legacy editor: https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/testing-gsuite-addons#legacy-editor

Comment: This is true for **Workspace** add-ons but it seems it's impossible to test **Editor** add-ons in the new editor. It looks like the author of this question develops a *Editor* add-on (because index.html is mentioned in the question).